# Финальные знаки препинания при прямой прямой речи или в цитате, когда кавычками заканчивается предложение или абзац

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, абзац

Как я понимаю, если предложение в самом конце абзаца, то все просто - в случае восклицания, вопроса или многоточия знаки перед заключительными кавычками и без финальной точки:

"Ваш пирог - это фантастика!"

"Но это уже другая история..."

"Так мы впервые встретились".

Но я чувствую себя некомфортно, когда предложение без точки, и предложением абзац не заканчивается:

И тут он воскликнул: "Ты не можешь играть в футбол в таких ботинках, без остроконечного носка!» На что я сухо пробормотал себе под нос...

Нужна ли точка после - носка!» ?

Answer (score 0):

Точка НЕ нужна.

Если прямая речь принадлежит разным лицам, то каждая реплика выделяется кавычками отдельно:

а) реплики отделяются друг от друга знаком тире: «Самовар – готов?» – «Нет еще…» – «Отчего? Там пришел кто-то». – «Авдотья Гавриловна» (М. Г.);

б) если одна из реплик сопровождается вводящими авторскими словами, то следующая не отделяется знаком тире: «Вы ведь вдова?» – спросил он тихо. «Третий год». – «Долго были замужем-то?» – «Год и пять месяцев…» (М. Г.);

в) точка и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам и снабженными разными авторскими словами: Проходя мимо, он сказал: «Не забудь купить билеты». – «Постараюсь», – ответила я ; **если же в первой реплике имеются знаки восклицательный или вопросительный, точка опускается**: Проходя мимо, он крикнул: «Не унывай!» – «Постараюсь», – ответила я ;

г) запятая и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам, но объединенными общим авторским предложением: Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», – «Да, недурно», – отвечал он обыкновенно (Г.); если же в первой реплике имеются знаки восклицательный или вопросительный, запятая опускается: Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» – «Мне холодно», – ответил он ; то же при ином расположении частей авторского предложения: Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» – он ответил: «Мне холодно» (Ток.).